# Why bash script breaks if it meets space in this example?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to execute following command on multiple servers:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -psecret mydatabase -e 'SELECT 1;'
```

So, i have `test1.sh` script, which echo-es dynamic string:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -psecret mydatabase -e 'SELECT 1'"
```

And `test2.sh` script, who executes the given string:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=`./test1.sh`
$CMD
```

If i execute `./test2.sh, i will see help output, command will be not executed.

If i remove spaces in mysql query `SELECT 1` or the whole `-e` param, and then execute `./test2.sh` script, everything works.

Why this is happening? Can you please describe this magic?

My bash version is 4.2.46.

Comment: Don't put commands in variables, use arrays. Also the reason is doesn't work is quote expansion occurs before variable so you will get two arguments passed to mysql `'SELECT` and `1'` instead of one.

Comment: @123 So, i should print array then? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using two scripts?

Comment: @123 unfortunately, yes. Black magic, that was being raised for years :( and moreover, a will to understand why it work that way.

Comment: Not sure i understand. Are you able to edit both scripts?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly escaping Select\ 1; and not using quote expansion?

Comment: @farsil That won't work for the same reason.

Comment: @Bernhard Not dupe, as they have two files so cannot use the answers from that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As long as you control and trust command line coming from `test1.sh`**, you can use dreaded `eval` in `test2.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="$(./test1.sh)"
eval "$cmd"
```

[Why and when should eval use be avoided in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: I'd still be interested in what's the flaw with OP's solution.

Comment: @timgeb i explained it in the comments below the question.

Comment: Thanks @123, yes indeed that's the reason why building a command using *command substitution* won't work in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try **test1.sh** script as like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -psecret mydatabase -e"
```

**test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=$(./test1.sh)
${CMD} "SELECT 1"
```